# Banner getting pushed down on screen resize

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So i have a slider banner `floated right` and set to `76% width` and a logo `floated left` set to `23.9% width`. So when the screen gets smaller these items re-size next to each other to fit in the screen.

The problem im having is the banner is getting pushed down. I can set a media query and push it back up with a margin adjustment however i feel like there is a better way.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: There seems to be some Javascript stuff happening on resize inside the slider banner. I assume it interferes with your intended layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a breakpoint with `.logo { float: none; }`. Remove this.

`(max-width: 979px) and (min-width: 769px)`